# Explain the verb tense in "All that glitters is not gold"

Tags: sentence-structure

I am confused by the maxim ***All that glitters is not gold***.

May I know why the word **is**  is used there?

In my known according the English grammar **glitters** is plural, So after plural we add verb+s.

As in above example use auxiliary verb so why not **are** – why **is**?

Comment: This is similar to my question last year, http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/74072/when-all-you-hear-is-fear-and-lies. There are good answers in there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Good question, but it's worth pointing out that *glitters* in this context is a verb, not a noun. The subject of the sentence is *all*.

When *all* is used as the subject of a sentence, it functions as a pronoun, and it can function as a singular or a plural pronoun. From NOAD:

> **all** (*pronoun*) [with clause ] the only thing (used for emphasis) : *all I want is to be left alone*.
>
> (used to refer to surroundings or a situation in general) everything : *all was well | it was all very strange*.

So:

> ***All** that glitters **is** not gold*

is roughly equivalent to

> ***Everything** that glitters **is** not gold*

and the verb tense agrees.

but:

> ***All** who eat **are** not gluttons*

is roughly equivalent to:

> ***All the people** who eat **are** not gluttons*

so there is no problem there, either.

Answer (score 0):

Grammatically is is used with third person singular and also s form of verb is used. "All" indicates a third person single group.